# Edit workspace settings first when interacting with UI on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way that using the UI to edit some setting (e.g. increasing the zoom level) applies the change to the current workspace only instead of globally? I have been checking in the settings themselves looking for a way to enable this, but haven't found it.

I mean that for example, if I press `ctrl - +` to increase zoom level while I'm editing code, this setting is written to the global `settings.json`. I'd like these kind of changes to be applied to the workspace settings (i.e. `${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/settings.json`) instead.

Comment: Right under where you could enter a search term in the Settings UI are two options:  User and Workspace.  If you select `Workspace` any settings changes will apply to the current workspace only.

Comment: Hi @Mark, sorry I should have written the question clearer. I mean that for example, if I press `ctrl-+` to increase zoom level while I'm editing code, this setting is written to the global `settings.json` instead of at the workspace level.

Comment: There is something interesting that I'll put into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the behaviour you are experiencing.  A change in zoom level is written to the User settings.  I looked at a few related issues and saw this interesting one: [Allow shortcuts for workspace-level zoom](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116701)

If you create a workspace-level setting for the zoom level, then any subsequent zooms are written to the **workspace** settings.  This is true even if you zoom out to zoom level 0 again (the default).

So it appears to work as you wish (I only tested on the zoom settings) if you first create a workspace zoom setting. Of course, you would have to first do that for all your workspaces, which is sub-optimal...  But at least it works thereafter.

Comment: Thanks! I guess for the time being is the closest to the behaviour I want